# Angular5 ParamMap and HttpClient

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular5

How can I get ParamMap to work with the HttpClient via a service in Angular5?

Component

```
// importing the service, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap, switchMap, etc

public value;
constructor(private myService: MyService, private activatedRouter: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.value = this.activatedRouter.paramMap
    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.myService.getOne(params.get('id')));
  }
```

Service

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
// ...
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
getOne(id) {
    return this.httpClient.get(`http://my.api/${id}`);
  }
```

At the moment if I do `console.log(this.value)` in my component I get a `AnonymousSubject`.

The question is, how can I use ParamMap and get the value from the HttpClient? I know I could use a router snapshot - which I have done and it works but I'd like to get this example working as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on CozyAzure's comment the final solution is

```
this.activatedRouter.paramMap
    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
      this.myService.getOne(params.get('id')))
      .subscribe(data => value = data);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need subscribe() to get the data. it's in the subscribe where you get the data

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.activatedRouter.paramMap
   .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>   
      this.myService.getOne(params.get('id'))).subscribe((data:any)=>{
           this.value=data
   });
 }
```

Comment: You should subscribe after the `switchMap()`, not at the service.

Comment: @CozyAxure, it's good your aclaration and my code is "very bad" formatted, but check the parentheses :)